# Input tag not rendered if the input tag put in foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For some reason, the input tags aren't displayed if I put them in a foreach loop.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.KhuyenMais) { 
    <input class="form-control" name="SoLuongKM" value="@item.SoLuong" />
}
```

Comment: Make sure the model have values....
Could you paste the html source code after opening the page

Answer (score 1):

You can check and display when the model don't have item

```
@if(Model.KhuyenMais != null && Model.KhuyenMais.Count > 0)
{
     foreach (var item in Model.KhuyenMais) 
     { 
        <input class="form-control" name="SoLuongKM" value="@item.SoLuong"/>
     }
}
else
{
   <span> There is no result </span>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is correct syntax and always render input tag.

You need check `Model.KhuyenMais` may be its length is zero.

```
<p>KhuyenMais count: @Model.KhuyenMais.Count</p>

@foreach (var item in Model.KhuyenMais) { 
    <input class="form-control" name="SoLuongKM" value="@item.SoLuong" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your model does not have the values `Model.KhuyenMais`.

See the following code snippet:

.CSHTML file code

```
@foreach (var item in MyWebApp.Controllers.MyClass.AssetList )
{
    <input class="form-control" name="SoLuongKM" value="@item.AssetName" />
}
```

C# Controllers file code

```
public ActionResult TreeListExport()
{
    List<Asset> oAsset = new List<Asset>();

    oAsset.Add(new Asset {AssetId =1, AssetName ="computer"});
    oAsset.Add(new Asset {AssetId =1, AssetName ="keyboard"});
    oAsset.Add(new Asset {AssetId =1, AssetName ="mouse"});

    MyClass.AssetList = oAsset;

    return View();
}
```